# Multiple versions of endpoint to appear in Swagger UI with WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I am using WebAPI MVC with .net framework. I am trying to get multiple versions of endpoints in my controller to appear. I have an obsolete 1.0 and a current 1.1. In the Swagger UI it just shows a crossed out 1.0. I would like to see 1.1 below it. Both 1.0 and 1.1 work if I call them.

```
public class FooController : BaseFundApiController<FooRequest>
{
    [Obsolete]
    [ApiVersion("1.0")]
    [Route("api/v1.0/Foo")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(FooResponse))]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> FooInfo([FromBody] FooRequest FooRequest)
    {
    }

    [ApiVersion("1.1")]
    [Route("api/v1.1/Foo")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(FooResponse))]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> FooInfo2([FromBody] FooRequest FooRequest)
    {
    }
}
```

Here is the appropriate bits for the webapi routing

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}"
    );

    var constraintResolver = new DefaultInlineConstraintResolver
    {
    ConstraintMap =
    {
        ["apiVersion"] = typeof( ApiVersionRouteConstraint )
    }
    };
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(constraintResolver);
    config.AddApiVersioning();
    }
}
```

How do I get both versions of the endpoint to appear?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out the ApiVersion should be 1.0

```
   [ApiVersion("1.0")]
    [Route("api/v1.1/Foo")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(FooResponse))]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> FooInfo2([FromBody] FooRequest FooRequest)
    {
    }
```